# Yii Bootstrap TbGridView overwrite summery text

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am using `bootstrap extension` in my `yii` project. The project has so many `grid-view` with summary text Their summery text is `{model name} {start} - {end} of {count}` . I used `grid-view` to overwrite summery text:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id' => 'grid1',
    'fixedHeader' => true,
    'type' => 'listtable',
    'template' => "{items}{pager}{summary}",
    'summaryText' => 'my text',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'htmlOptions' => array(),
    'columns' => array(
        // .. 
    )
));
```

And now I don't want to write each grid `'summaryText' => 'Shown'.' {end} '.'out of'.' {count}',`. I decided to show the same text all `grid-view`s. I don't know how to do it.  May I do it inside TbGridView or Where I must set `summaryText`.
[Here is summaryText doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#summaryText-detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the code inside `TbExtendedGridView` class `init` function

```
/**
    * Widget initialization
*/
    public function init()
    {
        $this->summaryText="Your sumary text";
      .....
   }
```